# What does POSIX mean by "two's complement representation" in stdint.h?

Tags: c, posix, language-lawyer

It's a well-known fact that signed integer overflow invokes undefined behavior, and that bitwise manipulation of signed integers is unreliable at best.  Thus, I found this line in [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdint.h.html) rather curious:

> The typedef name int N _t designates a signed integer type with width N, no padding bits, **and a two's-complement representation.** Thus, int8_t denotes a signed integer type with a width of exactly 8 bits.

This is a rather nebulous statement, which could mean any combination of these things:

1. The range of `intN_t` is from `INTN_MIN` to `INTN_MAX`.
2. `sizeof(intN_t) == N/8`
3. Bitwise operations on `intN_t` behave as expected for a two's complement representation.  `-1 ^ x == ~x` for every `x`, after inserting `intN_t` casts everywhere.
4. `intN_t` cannot have trap representations (and an optimizing compiler must not exploit possible traps).
5. Overflow of an `intN_t` variable is defined behavior (and wraps from `INTN_MAX` to `INTN_MIN`).

(1) and (2) both seem pretty obviously true to me, based on the rest of the document.  (1) is explicitly specified by the definition of `INTN_MIN`/`MAX`.  (2) is implied by "no padding bits."

**Which of (3), (4), and (5) are required by POSIX, if any?**

Comment: Regarding (2) - Why `8`?

Comment: @ecatmur because for POSIX `CHAR_BIT` equals 8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TL;DR

**1**, **3**, **4** are true on any C99, C11 compiler where `intN_t` exists. **2** is true on any C11 compiler where `int8_t` is present - because the presence of `int8_t` implies that `CHAR_BIT` is 8. **5** specifically not required by C - behaviour on signed integer overflow is undefined.

POSIX restricts the allowed C implementations so that `CHAR_BIT` must be 8 and integer representation is two's complement. Therefore a compliant C99/C11 compiler on a POSIX platform must have `int8_t`, which makes statements **1**, **2**, **3** and **4** true on POSIX. Since POSIX does not say anything about signed integer overflow, it remains undefined, therefore **5** is false.

---

The quoted sentence is taken *verbatim* from C11 (C99) standard. [C11 7.20.1.1p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.1p1):

> The typedef name `intN_t` designates a signed integer type with width `N`, no padding bits, and a **two's complement representation**. Thus, `int8_t` denotes such a signed integer type with a width of exactly 8 bits.

`int8_t` is *optional* in C, so the mere presence of this fragment in the standard doesn't even require 2's complement representation. [C11 7.20.1.1p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.1p3):

> These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a two's complement representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names.

Of your original statements,

1. is of course true, but such thing doesn't follow from **two's complement representation**. `int` ranges from `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX` on any one's complement architecture too. However, what follows from this is that the `INTN_MIN` has value [image].
2. **does not** follow from **two's complement representation**. `sizeof(intN_t)` is `N / CHAR_BIT`. However, POSIX requires that`CHAR_BIT` is 8 so `sizeof(intN_t)` indeed is `N / 8`
3. This is the only thing that follows from **two's complement  representation**
4. **does not** follow from **a two's complement representation** but the combination of 2's complement and that there are no padding bits.
5. **does not** follow from **a two's complement representation**, and is required by **neither C nor POSIX**.

---

The type `int8_t` is not specified by POSIX but the C99, C11 that POSIX adopts and augments. POSIX adds two restrictions:
  * that `CHAR_BIT` must be exactly 8 and not greater, even though allowed by the C programming language
  * that one's complement or the sign and magnitude representations for integer numbers are not allowed, even if they would be allowed by the C programming language

C99, C11 specify that *if present*, the types `intN_t` must have exactly so many bits with no padding bits, and 2's complement. If `int8_t` exists, its `sizeof` must be 1, because it is a synonym for `signed char` then and `CHAR_BIT` is equal to 8.

There will not be a trap representations of `intN_t` but it doesn't mean that those objects with decidedly *indeterminate* values must have the same value all over, or that the passing such values to library functions will have defined behaviour. Consider the following fragment:

```
int32_t *foo = malloc(sizeof(int32_t));
printf(PRId32 "\n", *foo);
printf(PRId32 "\n", *foo);
free(foo);
```

The compiler need not even call `malloc`; it could compile this to the equivalent of `puts("42\n666");` - even though there are no trap values of type `int32_t`. This  is because [`malloc`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.4p2):

> [...] allocates space for an object whose size is specified by size and **whose value is indeterminate**.

And indeterminate really means [unstable; indeterminable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394907/c-is-an-indeterminate-value-indeterminable)

---

Behaviour on signed integer overflow remains always undefined.

Comment: When I wrote `INTN_MIN`/`MAX`, I was actually referring to the mathematical values given elsewhere in the standard (i.e. -2^(N-1) to 2^(N-1) - 1), which are what you get with a typical implementation of two's complement.

Comment: @Kevin the C standard gives only 3 possible number formats: sign and magnitude, 1's complement and 2's complement. The 2's complement in POSIX refers to the 2's complement as defined in C and the "typical" is the only one allowed. But yeah, I've noted the number above.

Comment: I'm not sure that not having trap representations can be deduced from two's complement and no padding bits. Only the high bit set could be a trap, but the high bit set and the low bit set could be `INT_MIN` (or `-INT_MAX`).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala--СлаваУкраїні "the C standard gives only 3 possible number formats" - only as of C99 (C89 left it fully unspecified). However, we can probably safely assume that C99 only permitted itself to narrow it down to those three because no C implementation existed which used anything else.