# Initialize a pointer to an object

Tags: c++, pointers

Given an object, e.g. listNode.

If I initialize a pointer to an object with:

```
listNode* head_node;
```

How is this any different from

```
listNode* head_node = NULL;
```

Comment: Well, in the first case you don’t initialize it. It can be any value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423673/what-is-indeterminate-value

Comment: @dyukha It's not so much that is can have any value. It's value is indeterminate. Reading it is UB which goes beyond simply not knowing what the value is.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, Dereferencing it is UB.  Reading it isn't.

Comment: As far as I can tell in the standard, only "[o]bjects with static or thread storage duration are zero-initialized, see 6.8.3.2." As this is neither of those, it has an indeterminate value (Section 6.6.4).

Answer (score 1):

In the first case `listNode* head_node;` the compiler will allocate some memory to hold the pointer.  That memory can contain any value (for example it could be some random value from when that location was used for something else) and, in fact, reading it will result in undefined behavior.

In the second case `listNode* head_node = NULL;`, the compiler will allocate some memory to hold the pointer and then write `NULL` to that location so the pointer is guaranteed to be `NULL`.

One thing to note, you should use `nullptr` as opposed to `NULL`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509734/null-vs-nullptr-why-was-it-replaced) for why.

Comment: Because that's a separate topic so I didn't want to pollute the answer.  But thanks for the link.

Comment: Thanks, made a clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you are declaring a pointer variable. In the second case, you are declaring a pointer variable and initializing it to `NULL`. Any variable that is declared but not initialized leads to *undefined behaviour* when you try to access the variable. This has nothing to do specifically with pointers, pointers are just like any other variable. For example, if you write `int a;` and then you `cout << a;` you will see that `a` most likely has a random integer value written in it. But if you write `int a = 0;` and then you `cout << a;` you will see that `a` is always 0 on any compiler on any machine. This is well defined behaviour as opposed to undefined behaviour.

I would discourage the use of raw pointers in your case, as you most likely want always them to be initialized to `nullptr`, plus your listNode is most likely "owned" by the list itself. Try to use `std::unique_ptr<listNode>` instead: it will both initialize you pointer to `nullptr` by default and release the allocated memory when the pointer goes out of scope, meaning that if the head of the list will be deleted, all the other nodes in the list will automatically be deleted as well.