# Using operator "/=" at 'declare&initialize' part

Tags: c++

I'm a student who got interested in computer science recently. I'm studying C++ because I am interested in embedded systems.

When I tried to test the operator `/=` on my own. I want to learn about it by doing. The code that I wrote was

int a /= --b + 3;

but the compiler gave me an error message. But when I modified it to

```
int a = 0;
a /= --b + 3;`
```

it worked well. I thought it is related to l-values and r-values. Why does the 1st example with operator `/=` give me an error but the 2nd example above is ok? Can I ask you for some reference to get a hint about this question?

PS: When I tested with

```
int t = t / (--a + 3);
```

it worked well too! What is the  difference? Can you point me to some document about that?

Comment: What would you expect the result to be?

Comment: `int t=t/(--a+3);` does not "work well" – it has undefined behaviour because you're using the value of `t` before it has one. A decent compiler will warn you about this.

Comment: Read about the [mcve]. I believe you can cut your example down to `int main() { int a /= 2; int b = 4; b /= 2; int c = c / 2;}`. (Think about what value the variable might have when you divide it in each case.)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will refer that document! Thanks!

Comment: About the result was:
Expected: 0 (next line) 1 (next line) 0

Actual: the line "int a /= --b + 3;" displayed error that "there are no ; before /= "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a /= b;
```

is the same as:

```
a = a / b;
```

so this means that this below statement makes no sense:

```
int a /= (--b + 3);
```

Because it's equivalent to:

```
int a = a / (--b + 3);
```

Assuming that `b` has already been defined here; the problem is that `a` hasn't been defined, and so can't be used as part of the assignment.

The problem here is the same as the problem with this statement:

```
int a = a;
```

This also explains why the following code *does* work:

```
int a = 0;
a /= (--b + 3);
```

Because it's equivalent to this:

```
int a = 0;
a = a / (--b + 3);
```

Because `a` is known in the second line above, the RHS can be defined, and the new value for `a` determined.

More generally, operators like `/=`, `*=`, `+=`, `-=` and `%=` shouldn't be used during initialisation of a variable. A compiler (such as g++) should respond with an error if you ever try to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your help! So, you mean that the variable 'a' wasn't declared before with initialization so that made the problem? Is it right?

Comment: Yes. "/=" cannot be used with initialisation. The compiler should provide an error because this does not make sense.

Comment: I got it! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @정지수, I'm happy to hear that. If you found that my response answered your question, please consider marking it as the answer (the green tick next to my response).

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

I would like to mention two things.

- What is the meaning of this code?
- Is it valid C++ syntax?

Let's take a look at both.

> when I tested "int a/=--b+3", it has error but when I modified to "int a=0;
>
> a/=--b+3;" , it works well.

Unlike Java, C/C++ does not automatically initialize integer's value by 0 and it contains a [garbage value](http://programmersbhawa.com/garbage-value-c-produces/)(called "indeterminate value" officially). So `int a/=--b+3;` is more like `int a; a/=--b+3;` which is still be a meaningless value.

And when you declare a variable, C/C++ grammar does not allow `/=`. Here are the ways for variable declaration and initialization. I'm not sure there is more ways.

- `int a = 1;`
- `int a(1);`
- `int a{1};` (since C++11)

Comment: You should probably have used the appropriate term "indeterminate value" and mentioned that reading an indeterminate value is undefined behaviour. – *I'm not sure there is more ways.* – `int a{};` ^^

Comment: Thank you for your help! So it can be related with property of C++ and initialization!
Thank you!

Comment: @Swordfish I had not heard about the official term "indeterminate value" before. Just updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: [What is \[an\] Indeterminate Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423673/what-is-indeterminate-value)